# fatal error LNK1181 when building cocos2dx game project for x64(64bit) in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, cocos2d-x

I have created a project with Cocos2dx-2.5.5. I have built it for Win32, it works fine.
but now I am  opening it in Visual studio 2013 with Debug configuration as x64(64 bit). when I am building it for local machine I am getting the following error.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libcocos2d, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: libExtensions, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libpng.lib'
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'zlib.lib'
3>------ Build started: Project: Monroe_2013, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libEGL.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I opened proj.winrt folder with VS2013 from my project's root folder.

I have also tried adding directory to Configuration->Linker but couldn't get it work.

[image]

As you can see there are all the libraries added, which are causing that error.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a bunch of dlls, but the linker is complaining about missing libs...

Comment: @dlf : ok but then why does it build correctly for Win32 ? am I missing something here ?

Comment: I can't say without seeing the project, but I'd guess the Win32 build configuration has its linker inputs/search directories/something else set differently than the x64 configuration. If you switch back and forth between the two in the dialog and look for what changes, it might help you zero in on the problem.